# Can kafka streams restart crashed stream threads?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I couldn't find anything on this in the documentation. Consider you have  `props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 2);`
and a stream task crashes with an uncaught exception.
Can you somehow force its restart? Based on my experiments, crashed processor threads don't restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this with out relaunching the client. The ability to close the crashed threads and create replacements along with improved exception handling will be introduced in version 2.8.

[adding threads](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-663%3A+API+to+Start+and+Shut+Down+Stream+Threads)

[restarting on failure](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-671%3A+Introduce+Kafka+Streams+Specific+Uncaught+Exception+Handler)

Comment: Thanks! Slightly related, but is there any recommended orchestration tool to operate a cluster of streams applications?

Comment: @wcarlson: can you add the KIP/Jira links to your answer? This allows people to see when the new feature will be available.

Comment: @zeller There is no recommendation. A lot of people use Kubernetes nowadays, but KafkaStreams works with any tool of your liking.